# XSD Schema: Override an inherited element of a base complexType

Tags: c#, inheritance, xsd, schema, xsd.exe

We have started using schemas to generate C# classes for us and I am basically trying to replicate a class that has overridden a member inherited from it's base class.  I have done a lot of searching around and am fairly new to XSDs so I don't know if I am going about it all wrong or if it's just not possible.  Here is a simplified example of what I am trying to accomplish.

```
<xs:complexType name="ClientBase" abstract="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Company" type="CompanyBase" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>  
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="CompanyBase" abstract="true">
    <xs:attribute name="Id" type="xs:int" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Company">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="CompanyBase">
        <xs:attribute name="PartnerId" type="xs:int" use="required" />
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Client">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="ClientBase">
        <xs:sequence>
          <!-- error occurs here -->
          <xs:element name="Company" type="Company" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

This obviously doesn't work as it blows up on my Client type giving me the error that "Multiple definition of element 'Company' causes the content model to become ambiguous".

My goal is to end up with something that represents this.

```
    public abstract class CompanyBase
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

    }
    public class Company : CompanyBase
    {
        public int PartnerId { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class ClientBase
    {
        public CompanyBase[] Company { get; set; }
    }

    public class Client : ClientBase
    {
        new public Company[] Company { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your complex type called **Client**, which you're specifying as having an element named **Company**, extends **ClientBase**, which already contains an element named **Company** (which is of type CompanyBase.)  Hence, you have a redundancy in your element names.

Also: For your complex types, I recommend following a naming convention in your schemas that clarifies that they are types, not global elements.  I.e., name your complex types as **[Typename]Type**, rather than **[Typename]**.  It makes things much less confusing in the long run, and you can avoid name collisions with your global elements as well.

Comment: Thank you, yes I understand the cause of the error I am getting.  What I am wondering is if there is another way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sorry!  Here's a couple of ideas: 1) You could rename your array in class Client, from Company to Companies. 2) You could move Client and ClientBase to a separate namespace, which would enable you to have elements with the same name.